# How to conditionally append incremented suffix to vector in R

Tags: r, vector, append, increment

I have a character vector in R with reoccurring values:

```
vec <- c('22','22','22','45','45','45','56','67','67','67','89','90')
```

I want to append _1, _2, _3 to similar values in the vector to get a vector like:

```
vec <- c('22_1','22_2','22_3','45_1','45_2','45_3','56'_1,'67_1','67_2' ...
```

My question is how do I increment conditionally ('56' is singular and does not need an appended value). I have tried writing a loop and store occurrence counts in a list, but it is very verbose and I suspect there is an easier way of doing this within the apply family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ave` and get the sequence grouped by 'vec', then `paste` it with the original vector.

```
 res <- paste(vec, ave(vec, vec, FUN=seq_along), sep="_")
```

In case, we need to replace the `_1` from elements that have a frequency of 1, use `table` to get the frequency, subset the elements that matches the `names` of the 'table' having frequency 1 with the 'res' and remove the `_` followed by zero or more characters with `sub`.

```
 tbl <- table(vec)
 names(tbl)[tbl==1]
 i1 <- vec %in% names(tbl)[tbl==1]
 res[i1] <-  sub('_.*', '', res[i1])
 res
 #[1] "22_1" "22_2" "22_3" "45_1" "45_2" "45_3" "56"   "67_1" "67_2" "67_3"
 #[11] "89"   "90"
```

---

Or we can just use `make.unique`

```
 make.unique(vec, sep="_")
 #[1] "22"   "22_1" "22_2" "45"   "45_1" "45_2" "56"   "67"   "67_1" "67_2"
 #[11] "89"   "90"
```